# Need to define a cube based on a Postgre sql User defined function with string parameter

Tags: cube.js

I have a requirement to create a cube that is based on an existing PostgreSQL user-defined function with a string parameter as input. And the parameters will be supplied from the Rest API call to Cube.js. Is it possible to build such a cube? Or what's the best way to implement it?

Below is a sample code I tried but it gives me an error "Referencev_value is not defined"

cube('New1', {
sql: () => `SELECT * FROM test.ufn_function(${v_value})`,
dimensions: {
is_total: {
sql: 'id',
type: 'number',
primary_key: true,
shown: true
},
"name": {
sql: '"name"',
type: 'number'
}
},
});

Related Cube.js-generated SQL

this is not getting generated due to error.

Can some one help me here?

Comment: I found a way to do this, but not sure if this is the right approach. I have changed the cube definition like below and send the params as payload in API call cube('New1', { sql: () => SELECT * FROM test.ufn_function(${SECURITY_CONTEXT.type.unsafeValue()}), dimensions: { is_total: { sql: 'id', type: 'number', primary_key: true, shown: true }, "name": { sql: '"name"', type: 'number' } }, });